# dynamically create 2 conditional variable for pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads, conditional-statements

Pthreads related question.

Say i want to dynamically create 2 conditional variable.

Will this do the job :

```
pthread_cond_t * a = new pthread_cond_t();
pthread_cond_t * b = new pthread_cond_t();

pthread_cond_init(&a , NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&b , NULL);
```

Or maybe they are the same conditional variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be 2 separate variables, but they are pointers so the initialisation should be:

```
pthread_cond_init(a , NULL);
pthread_cond_init(b , NULL);
```